# Change URL for custom layout on local router in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have developed a flutter web application structured as follows

```
base-layout
 - Dashboard
 - Overview 
 - Manage Drivers
 - Manage Transections
```

The base-layout has a top bar ,side bar and content area.

The top bar and the side menu does not re-render on click of menu items only the content area renders to the pages specified above in the structure.
on Click of the side menu items, it opens the proper named-route and displays the content.

There is not option where i can:

1. Change the URL on the click of the side menu item within the base-layout.
2. Since the local router has no option specified in (1) i cannot share the link to another person as it will always come to the landing page ie: maybe the dashboard page on the base-layout configured to have the base named-route

Comment: use Navigator v2

Comment: The navigator 2 also doesn't have a solution to it because no doubt it navigates between the different pages on same layout but the whole layout get rendered along with page change this fixes the the url issue but the whole layout shouldn't rerender.                                                              If same layout is used then route doesn't update in url